# How many people have been instantly killed by smoking?

Tags: smoking, statistics, death, nicotine

We all know that cigarettes have killed millions of people, to the extent that just about everyone knows someone who has died from it. Smoking deaths are overwhelmingly medium to long term effects of smoke inhalation and exposure (citation?). I am looking for short term effects leading to death. So anything from extreme allergic reaction (is that even possible?) to dropping the cigarette into gasoline, you name it as long as it's fatal. There are [news stories](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/health/news/8855924/Deaths-from-bee-stings-chair-falls-and-boiling-water.html) disseminating statistics on deaths caused by all sorts of animals or even types of furniture. Are there comparable statistics collected on deaths due to cigarettes?

This could also apply to tobacco in general but I am asking about cigarettes specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** maybe a few, but not instantly.

Nicotine poisoning exists but rarely is it fatal. Especially, when it is delivered through smoking.

There have been very few incidents of death by nicotine poisoning reported.

**References:**

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotine_poisoning
2. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0379073809004459
3. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0379073810000459

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful and well researched answer. I was completely unaware of the strong toxicity of nicotine. I will accept your answer if nobody else posts here in the next few days.